# C# Constraints on Type Parameters what to use for bool

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

```
public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxListFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression) where TValue : bool
```

and `bool` is not valid. `Boolean` is also not valid. What can I use? TValue must be `bool` ?

edit: I am writing HTMLHELPER for mvc3 and later onis used as `html.CheckBoxFor(expression)` so `TValue` must be generic

Comment: Using a constraint on a specific type is usually a sign you're doing something wrong. Why use a constraint? Why not simply `Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression`

Answer (score 0):

If `TValue` must be `bool`, it musn't be generic.

```
public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxListFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression)
```

Comment: how can i then prevent that TValue is later of type bool?

Comment: Do you want it to be bool or do you want to prevent it from being bool?

Comment: @senzacionale What are you trying to do? Are you perhaps trying to create two versions of `CheckBoxListFor` - one for `TValue` being `bool`, one for it being anything else?

Comment: must be bool, but is html extension so must be generic TValue and not strict bool. I will use it later on html.CheckBoxFor(expression)

Comment: Why not use two different method then? Make one explicitly take a bool and the other one generic

Comment: but then i get error with this; html.CheckBoxFor(expression)

Answer (score 0):

Then just remove the `TValue` type parameter and replace it with `bool`:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxListFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression)
```

Comment: I don't think `CheckBoxListFor<TModel, bool>` will compile

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it looks to me like you need two different overloads:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxListFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> predicateExpression)
```

and

```
public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxListFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
```

Internally, you can share the inner implementation and add what you need.